# Software updater takes multiple tries

Tags: 18.04, update-manager, ubuntu-mate

I noticed that Software updater often takes multiple tries.

It usually says it can not download files even though my internet is fine.
It looks like it only partially downloads file on the first try.

I have a wired connection.

Is there fix for it?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`. Wired or Wireless connection?

Comment: Wired connection. What am I looking for in journalctl? @waltinator

Comment: The `journalctl` command in my answer outputs the time-stamped log entries. Examine the log entries from about 3 minutes before a failure. If there's nothing in your logs, look at the system you're connected to.